# jQuery: Count the occurrence of all different characters in input and compare with Json Array

Tags: jquery, json

I am needing this functionality: 
A json Objct contains a list of different characters and their amount:
Like this:

```
Object {A: "23", B: "46", C: "42", D: "49", E: "31"…}
```

The User types some text into an input and a script compares the user input with the loaded json-data. The goal is, that the user have a life feedback while he is typing that shows, how many characters are used and are available and to avoid that the user uses more characters as available.

the json comes here:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/wordpress-dev/wp-json/wp/v2/fonts/9/',   
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

    /// get all data (characters and their amount)
    /// the result looks like this: Object {A: "23", B: "46", C: "42", D: "49", E: "31"…}
    $.each(data.acf.schrift, function(key, value){
        geladenezeichen[value.zeichen]= value.anzahl;

        //build up ul with all characters and their amount
        $(".fonts-list-1").append("<li data-zeichen="+value.zeichen+"> <strong>" + value.zeichen + "</strong> <span>" + value.anzahl +"</span></li>");  
        });

    };
});
```

after loading this a list is generated with all characters and their amount.

If the user types something in the input the occurrence of every characters in the input will be counted and subtracted from the loaded json data.

```
  $("#input").on("change keydown input paste",function(e){

     //split input
    var input_as_array = (value.split(""));

    //count each character:
    var zeichen_to_count = {};  
    $.each(input_as_array,function(i,el){
        zeichen_to_count[el] = zeichen_to_count[el] + 1 || 1;
    });

    /// update ul with the results  
    $.each(zeichen_to_count, function(key, value){      
        $('*[data-zeichen="'+key+'"] span').text(">>>"+(geladenezeichen[key]-value));

        /// if to many characters used:
        if((geladenezeichen[key]-value+1) <=0){
            $('*[data-zeichen="'+key+'"] span').text(" error: to many characters used ");
        }

    });
});
```

My Problem is: lets say i have the amount of 23 available "A"s and i am typing an "A": the output is correct, it counts down to 0 and finally shows the error message. But when i am deleting the "A" in the input first everything looks good but after deleting the last "A" the script doesnot update the Amount (it stays at 22). The reason is probably the "each" function that does not fire if their is no "A" at all, or am i wrong here?
Does any one have an idea how to fix this? To get the result of "23" after deleting all "A"s?
Thanks alot!

Comment: Your analysis is exactly right. The code goes through the entered text, counting the letters that are entered. There are no As, so it doesn't do anything with the As. One fix would be to make the main loop go through the alphabet. Another would be to reset all the values to their default before running your existing loop.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean with reset all values before running the loop? Thank a lot!

Comment: I mean reset the content of .fonts-list-1 to its original state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through `geladenezeichen` and check if each property exists in `zeichen_to_count` and if it doesn't reset the value in corresponding element

Comment: thanks, `geladenezeichen`has much data, something like 200 different characters and their amount, how can I iterate through this every time the user typed a single letter? Is it possible to do this in a good performance?

Comment: Going through the object will be fast. The expensive part is searching the DOM for each element. Does user really need to see a list of 200 characters? Seems like it would be hard to visualize and watch that list while typing

Comment: ok, you thought like this? `var new_array = {};
$.each(geladenezeichen, function(key, value){
  //if exist: 
 if( jQuery.inArray( key, zeichen_to_count ) ){
  new_array [key] = value - zeichen_to_count[key];
 }else{
  new_array [key] = 0;
 }
});
`

Comment: `{}` is not an array...it is object. So you need to use something like `hasOwnProperty()`